# build vlc player ../src/parser/Task.h:28:10: fatal error: 'vlcpp/vlc.hpp' file not found

Tags: android, vlc, vlc-android

I follow [this](https://wiki.videolan.org/AndroidCompile/) guidance for cloning and build vlc media player.
but  when I run

```
 sh compile.sh -a armeabi-v7a
```

I get this error message in terminal

```
Entering directory `/home/user/Downloads/AndroidWorkSpace/Vlc/medialibrary/medialibrary/build-android-armeabi-v7a'
CXX      src/libmedialibrary_la-Artist.lo
CXX      src/libmedialibrary_la-Album.lo
CXX      src/libmedialibrary_la-AlbumTrack.lo
CXX      src/libmedialibrary_la-AudioTrack.lo
In file included from ../src/AudioTrack.cpp:29:
In file included from ../src/Media.h:30:
In file included from ../src/File.h:30:
In file included from ../src/parser/Parser.h:29:
../src/parser/Task.h:28:10: fatal error: 'vlcpp/vlc.hpp' file not found
#include <vlcpp/vlc.hpp>
```

can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score -1):

To do:

```
cp -rf  /path/to/your/vlc-android/medialibrary/libvlcpp/vlcpp /path/to/your/vlc-android/medialibrary/medialibrary/libvlcpp/
```